# Rcpp support for multiple variable types

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

Is there a way to write an Rcpp function that can receive a variable as one of two/several datatypes, and then does something different depending on the datatype?  In R this is something we hardly think about -- pass the variable in, check the class, decide what to do. In Rcpp everything needs to be fully specified. Is there something like a `SetClassUnion` for Rcpp?

For example, I have two largely overlapping Rcpp functions, one which receives `arma::SpMat A` and another which receives `arma::mat A`. If I really need two separate functions for this, it's a ton of code redundancy.

```
// RcppArmadillo

arma::mat Foo(const arma::SpMat<double>& A) {
 // how might I check class of "A" and return "A" as dense
}

arma::mat Foo(const arma::mat<double>& A) {
 // still I'd like to check the class of "A" and only return "A" if it is dense
 return(A);
}
```

Comment: Very related materual has been discussed many times as we have a _general problem_ between what R does _at run-time_ and what C++ and other types languages _offer at compile-time_.  So you need to switch "inside"  a function between `int`, `double`, ... payloads, and same for dense vs sparse matrices.  Maybe do some searches for `typeof` here, also look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201929/checking-multiple-inheritance-of-s4-objects-in-rcpp (from just yesterday !!) and the thread at r-devel it lead to.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thanks Dirk. The difference between run-time and compile-time is understandable. And fortunately this is not an "issue", it's simply an "inconvenience". I'm not seeing any solutions with `typeof`, or any potential to translate the suggestions in the recently asked question on S4 R inheritance (https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Checking-multiple-inheritance-of-S4-objects-using-R-s-C-API-td4767766.html). There must be a solution, but certainly not an obvious one.

Comment: There isn't. _Every exported-back-to-R signature_ is a C signature.  We've been at this for a dozen years, there aren't too many stones left unturned.  But hey, if you find one, we'll be all ears. The Rcpp Gallery is always open for new contributed posts...